# Puppeteer timeout in Firebase scheduled function during browser creation

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Im having trouble with puppeteer in Functions.
I am running the exact same code path from two different functions; one HTTP-triggered and one scheduled.

The HTTP-triggered functions works as intended. But the scheduled function times out with:

```
TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r869685 is guaranteed to work.
```

Is there a difference between the two functions?

```
    export const collectNews = functions
      .runWith({
        timeoutSeconds: 500,
        memory: "1GB",
      })
      .region("europe-west2")
      .pubsub.schedule("every 10 minutes")
      .onRun((context) => {
        mainFetchAndStoreArticles(db).then(() => {
          console.log("Fetched and stored articles! " + new Date());
        });
        return null;
      });
```

```
export const triggerCollectNews = functions
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
    memory: "1GB",
  })
  .region("europe-west2")
  .https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
      mainFetchAndStoreArticles(db).then(() => {
        response.send("Fetched and stored articles! " + new Date());
      });
    } else {
      response.send("Done");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the promise as you've figured it out. You can do so by directly adding a return like this:

```
return mainFetchAndStoreArticles(db)
```

or to handle the error in a better way (just in case you need to trigger something in case of error)

```
return mainFetchAndStoreArticles(db).then(() => {
  return response.send(...)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
  sendAlert(e)
  return null
})
// <-- don't return from out of the .then()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by returning the promise from `mainFetchAndStoreArticles` , instead of using .then() and returning null.